# Drag UIImageView out of ScrollView

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

I have a `RootViewController` with a `UIScrollViewController` (boardScrollView).
This `boardScrollView` has a `UIImageView` as subview (boardImage) to create the board. I can zoom in and out and scroll on the boardImage within the `boardScrollView`. Works great!

Now I want to drag & drop other `UIImageViews` into the boardScrollImage within the boardScrollView and also OUT of the `boardScrollView`.
For these other UIImageViews (Tiles) I have created a subclass of the `UIImageView` class (TileViewClass).

I have the drag&drop working to drop the Tile INTO the `boardScrollView/boardImage` and also drag&drop INSIDE the `boardScrollView/boardImage` but I can not get the drag&drop to OUTSIDE the `boardScrollView` working..
I think this is because I can not access the views in the `rootviewcontroller` from the subclass.

Maybe it is even better to place the Tile back to the topview (window) in touchesBegan, and so the determination of the drop-position is always done from the same view.
But I don't know how this can be done...

I have tried `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:self.dragObject];` in the touchesBegan method, but this does not do the trick....
Maybe I am missing a removeFromSuperView somewhere?

Anyone any idea how I can get the drag&drop working?

RootViewController.h:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>


@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *boardScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *dragObject;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint touchOffset;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint homePosition;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *boardImage;


@end
```

RootViewController.m:

```
@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize boardScrollView;
@synthesize dragObject;
@synthesize touchOffset;
@synthesize homePosition;
@synthesize boardImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyblue_numbered_15x15_900x900.png"];
    self.boardImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    self.boardImage.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};
    [self.boardScrollView addSubview:self.boardImage];

    self.boardImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    self.boardScrollView.contentSize = image.size;
    self.boardScrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
    self.boardScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.boardScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

}
```

TileImageView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TileImageView : UIImageView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *dragObject;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint touchOffset;


@end
```

TileImageView.m:

```
#import "TileImageView.h"


@implementation TileImageView
@synthesize dragObject;
@synthesize touchOffset;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.exclusiveTouch = YES;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if ([touches count] == 1) {
        // one finger

        CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
        for (UIImageView *iView in self.superview.subviews) {
            if ([iView isMemberOfClass:[TileImageView class]]) {
                if (touchPoint.x > iView.frame.origin.x &&
                    touchPoint.x < iView.frame.origin.x + iView.frame.size.width &&
                    touchPoint.y > iView.frame.origin.y &&
                    touchPoint.y < iView.frame.origin.y + iView.frame.size.height)
                {
                    self.dragObject = iView;
                    self.touchOffset = CGPointMake(touchPoint.x - iView.frame.origin.x,
                                                   touchPoint.y - iView.frame.origin.y);
                    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    CGRect newDragObjectFrame = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - touchOffset.x,
                                           touchPoint.y - touchOffset.y,
                                           self.dragObject.frame.size.width,
                                           self.dragObject.frame.size.height);
    self.dragObject.frame = newDragObjectFrame;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    for (UIView *iView in self.superview.subviews) {
        if ([iView isMemberOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        {
            CGPoint touchPointScreen = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
            if (touchPointScreen.x > iView.frame.origin.x &&
                touchPointScreen.x < iView.frame.origin.x + iView.frame.size.width &&
                touchPointScreen.y > iView.frame.origin.y &&
                touchPointScreen.y < iView.frame.origin.y + iView.frame.size.height)
            {
                for (UIView *iView2 in iView.subviews) {
                    [iView2 addSubview:self.dragObject];
                    CGPoint touchPointImage = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:iView2];

                    self.dragObject.frame = CGRectMake(touchPointImage.x - touchOffset.x,
                                                       touchPointImage.y - touchOffset.y,
                                                       self.dragObject.frame.size.width,
                                                       self.dragObject.frame.size.height);
                }
            } 
            self.dragObject = nil;

        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you'r catching all touch events on the tileimageview and moving its origin CGPoint around.
If a touch event ended, your cycling though all subviews of your tileviews superview.

If any1 of this is a UIScrollview, you try to locate if the touchpoint matches its frame.

So basically you just checking the frame of your uiscrollview. Therefore your touchpoint cannot be outside it.

Solution: you have to check the view in which you want to drop the tileimageview! you can assume that its a sibling of your uiscrollview(what i assume).

Other way, which i would recommend: Create a View - dropgroundview, in which you catch the touches(=> implement touchesend) 
there you can drop your views around and check for subclasses of e.g. dropviews.

Comment: No, I want to drop the Tile outside the uiScrollView. Therefor, I want to have the Tile as the topview of all views...

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I have delegated the touch methodes to the RootViewController. There, I have access to all subviews and most important: the highest view.

Here, I say:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tmpDragObject];
```

And then it works!